# Is it safe to use IDs on elements inside reusable Polymer components?

Tags: javascript, dom, polymer, polymer-1.0

The Polymer 0.5 FAQ states the following on this:

> **My components are producing markup with multiple ids of the same name.**
>
> The Shadow DOM polyfill tries hard to mimic native Shadow DOM, in that nodes with the same ids will still be encapsulated.
>
> However, you should avoid using DOM-level id referencing (e.g. `<label for>`) when using the polyfill. The id may not resolve correctly when under the Shadow DOM polyfill.

In Polymer 1.x does this still apply?  And if I do a document.getElementById, wouldn't that always return the first element in the DOM with that ID?  If a Polymer component is reused, wouldn't I need to first limit my scope to the component of interest, then call component.getElementById (or Polymer's component.$.ID)?

This of course has implications on accessing elements via testing frameworks as well.  An alternative is to use classes to access elements in a component (e.g. component.$$('.myClass')), but using IDs seems cleaner and oftentimes more appropriate.  More clarification on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It is never "safe" to use an ID more than once on the same page. Any reusable components should always use Classes. You already identified many of the reasons that this is risky - but also remember that you wont be able to use basic JS functions like getElementByID() when you have multiple instances using the same ID name.

Comment: I feel uncomfortable with this answer. Doesn't the Polymer.Base $ map evoke that component developers address local dom elements by id?

Comment: Maybe - after further reading, it looks like Polymer may map to the DOM node rather than the ID. If this is the case, while using multiple IDs with the same name may cause other issues, Polymer might not care.